# Shopify - Add Rates through external API

Tags: node.js, shopify, ejs

I am new in the Shopify Ecommerce platform (residing in South Africa) and I am trying to figure out, how to use an external (my own) API to get shipping rates based on postal codes from the Billing Address to the Shipping Address. I have went through sites after sites including youTube, and nothing was helpful. Is there a way to integrate Shopify with other API to calculate shipping rates? I am running everything on NodeJS, Express and Ngrok

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use Custom Carrier Services. You register a callback with the Shopify store, and then Shopify sends your App endpoint a payload for each and every checkout. It is a simple payload, you get the origin, destination, and items. So you can figure out shipping rates that are appropriate, and then return those to Shopify. Shopify then formats the results and presents them to the customer.